# In Magento 1.9.X how to call site2.com product list on site1.com through rest api

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, soap

I have two website and both are developed by magento 1.9.x vesion.

As Example:

```
1. www.example1.com
2. www.example2.com
```

Now I need to show product list in www.example1.com  from www.example2.com of some particular category through **SOAP**/**REST API**.

I go through the [Magento 1.x REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) But I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: What error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only the product list for a specific category on your site, then you can use rest API to fetch specific category's product from other site and make a custom collection then showing it on your destination site.

If you want to show the specific category product on your site and customer able to **Add to cart** , then you have to create product in your destination site.

> **Note:** when you create product on your destination server,that time
>   make sure product price are same as source server.